# Is there a way to pass a URL with a hash in it to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, url

if I have a URL of www.google.co.uk/test#number1 is there a way to pass the
`window.location.pathname;`
to a variable to read as `test#number1` rather than the variable terminating at the "#" hash symbol?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (with more info).**

What I was looking to achieve is populating a text box with the pathname of the current URL that contains hashes.

riscarrott's answer works perfectly but because I have <15 rep I can't up vote it. :(

`document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML =
window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;`

Comment: Do you want to read the current url or do you want to set the url with an hashtag?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What makes you think something will suddenly truncate the string at the `#`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `location.hash` contains all hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the hash on the location object too:

```
// https://www.google.co.uk/test#number1
var foo = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
console.log(foo) // "/test#number1"
```

MDN provides good documentation on the BOM -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: This works great, thank you very much!

Comment: The URI spec doesn't support multiple hash fragments -- https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5

Comment: Although testing in chrome I can see that 'https://www.google.co.uk/test#number1#number2' does work so `window.location.hash` === '#number1#number2'